# JPA setHint in all queries

Tags: jpa, java-ee-6

I need to set:

setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
setHint("org.hibernate.cacheMode", "NORMAL")

How can I set this in all queries without setting query by query?

Comment: According to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-querycache (point 20.4.1 "Enabling query caching") "by default, individual queries are not cached even after enabling query caching. To enable results caching for a particular query, call org.hibernate.Query.setCacheable(true). This call allows the query to look for existing cache results or add its results to the cache when it is executed."

Comment: @Ricardo No, you do not need to enable the caching for ALL queries. Just find the bottleneck (probably 3-5 queries) and correct only those.